# apache drill_superset_mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-superset, apache-drill

i tried to extract some fields from mongodb by using apache drill on superset,

the data is look like -
nameofcity:object
.collegename:array
0:object
.noOfstudet:300
I need to extract noOfstudet,i could extract noOfstudet till limit 100,After i got this error:-
"org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: In a list of type INT, encountered a value of type BIGINT. Drill does not support lists of different types."

i tried cast functon on the noOfstudet .cast(noOfstudet as BIGINT),but not work

Comment: Please add the version of Drill used and the value of the Drill option  store.mongo.bson.record.reader.